# Why do MySQL MyISAM table indexes go out of date?

Tags: mysql, index, myisam

I have few MyISAM tables, where only the auto_increment primary key is up to date with the number of columns, but not other indexes.

Any idea, why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a guess but here it goes...

The only way I know that a PRIMARY KEY for a MyISAM table would be OK and all secondary indexes be out-of-date would be under this unique circumstance:

Running this

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DISABLE KEYS;
```

and forgetting to undo it with

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ENABLE KEYS;
```

When you disable keys, the PRIMARY KEY and all UNIQUE keys are unaffected. When you enable keys, all secondary indexes get rebuilt.

According to [MySQL Documentation on `ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html):

> If you use ALTER TABLE on a MyISAM table, all nonunique indexes are created in a separate batch (as for REPAIR TABLE). This should make ALTER TABLE much faster when you have many indexes.
>
> This feature can be activated explicitly for a MyISAM table. ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS tells MySQL to stop updating nonunique indexes. ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE KEYS then should be used to re-create missing indexes. MySQL does this with a special algorithm that is much faster than inserting keys one by one, so disabling keys before performing bulk insert operations should give a considerable speedup. Using ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS requires the INDEX privilege in addition to the privileges mentioned earlier.
>
> While the nonunique indexes are disabled, they are ignored for statements such as SELECT and EXPLAIN that otherwise would use them.

## SUGGESTION

First, make a copy of the table.

Try running

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ENABLE KEYS;
```

and see if it does anything. If not, run

```
REPAIR TABLE mytable;
```

Give it a Try !!!